# How do I set BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher to notify all advertisements?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, windows-10, uwp

I'm working on a Win10 sample (BluetoothAdvertisement) to detect ibeacon advertisements, after modifying and running the sample for my needs, I can see only one advertisement per iBeacon in range.

I have to capture every advertisement from every ibeacon in range, is there any way to do that? I was looking at the BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter but nothing mentions that only one event per device will be triggered.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try stopping scanning and restarting to get a second detection.  On some chipset/driver implementations only one detection per unique bluetooth mac address is passed up the chain for each scan.  This is especially true when the device is sending connectable advertisements.

Several Android Bluetooth LE implementations have this same issue (e.g. the Nexus 4 and the Moto G.)  As a workaround, the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) stops and restarts scanning approximately once per second in order to get one callback per scan cycle from each device.   This same approach is planned for a port of this code to the [Windows Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/windows-beacon-library), which is a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scanning mode:

bleAdWatcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;

That seems to be working for me...